# CheckboxFor Master List and selected

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox, model-binding

I've got a model that contains a property that is a list of other objects.  There is also a master list of all of the sub objects.  I need to list all of the master objects in the form of checkboxes, but only check the ones that are assigned to main model.  This needs to be done in an editor template.

For example:

```
public class User
{
     // This contains a list of all roles the user belongs to
     public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
{

public class Role
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int ID { get; set; }
}


public class UserAdminModel
{
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

The main view

```
@model UserAdminModel

@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Users)
```

The editor template

```
@model User
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col class="checkbox-column"/>
        <col/>
    <col style="width:70px;"/>
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (Role role in allRoles)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor( ... )</td>
            <td>@role.ID
            <td>@role.Name</td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The main issue here is the Html.CheckBoxFor part.  I need to make sure that I get the correct ID of the user here so that it will model bind.  Something like User_*0*_Role_3.

Answer (score 0):

Editor template:

```
@model User
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col class="checkbox-column"/>
        <col/>
    <col style="width:70px;"/>
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Roles.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id, Model.Id)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Roles[i].Id)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Roles[i].Checked)</td>
            <td>@Model.Roles[i].Id</td>
            <td>@Model.Roles[i].Name</td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Role class:

```
public class Role
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(UserAdminModel model)
{
    //...
}
```