# CheckBoxFor value is always FALSE HTML /ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to display 2 fields one is checkbox and the another one is description in the case of the checkbox for some reason always is coming FALSE using CheckBoxFor the description is coming fine!

HTML Code

```
<table>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.PurchaseOrder.LineItems.Count(); i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>           
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.LineItems[i].Received)
              
            </td>
            <td>
                @Model.PurchaseOrder.LineItems.ToArray()[i].Description 
            </td>         
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Model

```
public class LineItem 
{
    [MaxLength(2000)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public bool Received { get; set; }
}
```

Model

```
public class PurchaseOrder 
{
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; } = new List<LineItem>();
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrder { get; set; }

    public List<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
}
```

I need to know how could be the reason that is coming FALSE the `CheckBoxFor` Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I don't see any `PurchaseOrder` property in `ViewModel` class. While in your HTML code contains `model.PurchaseOrder`. Please verify your model and possible to provide sample data in JSON. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you actually I forgot to add it but it is there now I updated. let me know if  you can know what is wrong.

Comment: Perhaps `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.PurchaseOrder.LineItems[i].Received)` instead of `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.LineItems[i].Received)`. As what you did now is referring data from two different arrays.

Comment: Yes doing in that way I got this error:
Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type IEnumeral <LineItem>

Comment: Hi sorry for that, use `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.PurchaseOrder.LineItems.ToArray()[i].Received)`. So the boolean value (`Received`) you are tried to get from `model.PurchaseOrder.LineItems`, same as `description`?

Comment: No problem ok doing like this I did not get error but anyways all the checks are in false I'm not sure why some of the records and in 1 and others in 0 it should show some records checked but are all unchecked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241055/discussion-between-yong-shun-and-german-bernal).